# filter using radio button

Tags: php, jquery, filter

Hi I have some products on a website I'm building that I want to be able to filter by the product range that they come from. I have managed to make a filter for specific brands using a drop down menu, but would like to be able to filter the range when clicking on a label/selecting a radio button. I am using php and jquery to try and achieve this, can anybody tell me where I'm going wrong and what I need to do to fix this?

This is my php/html which shows the options of product ranges.

```
<!-- Product Range -->
                         <div id="product_range">
<?php
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM `product_range`";
     $result = $conn->query($sql);

 if ($result->num_rows > 0){
     // Output data of each rowt
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
         //echo "Brand : " . $row["brand"] . " - Product : " . $row["name"] . " - " . $row["description"] . " - Price : " . $row["price"] . "<br>";
         echo    "<div class='col-lg-6 col-md-4 col-sm-5 col-xs-12 product_range " . $row['brandName'] . " all' id='products'>
                     <div class='hovereffect'>
                         <img class='img-responsive product_range_img' src='" . $row['img'] . "' alt=''>
                         <div class='overlay1'>
                             <h2> " . $row['name'] . "</h2>
                             <p> 
                                 " . $row['title'] . "
                             <br>
                             <br>
                             <form>
                                 <input type='radio' class='radio' name='selector' value='" . $row['product_range'] . "' />
                                 <label for='" . $row['product_range'] . "' id='labelSelect'>
                                     View Products
                                 </label>
                             </form>
                             </p>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                 </div>";

     }
 } else {
     echo "0 results";
 }

?>
                         </div>
```

I then have this part which is the products i wish to display on click.

```
<!-- Product packs -->
                         <div id="product_group">
<?php
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM `product_packs`";
     $result = $conn->query($sql);

     if ($result->num_rows > 0){
         // Output data of each rowt
          while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
             //echo "Brand : " . $row["brand"] . " - Product : " . $row["name"] . " - " . $row["description"] . " - Price : " . $row["price"] . "<br>";
             echo    "<div class='col-lg-2.4 col-md-3.4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 products " . $row['brandName'] . " all " . $row['product_range'] . "' id='products'>
                         <div class='hovereffect'>
                             <img class='img-responsive productimg' src='" . $row['img'] . "' alt=''>
                             <div class='overlay1'>
                                 <h2> " . $row['name'] . "</h2>
                                 <p> 
                                     " . $row['title'] . "
                                 <br>
                                     " . $row['header'] . "
                                 <br>
                                 <br>
                                     " . $row['price'] . "
                                 <br>
                                 <a href='#'>
                                     Add To Cart 
                                 </a> 
                                 </p>
                             </div>
                             <div class='overlay2'>
                             <div class='overlay3'>
                                 <p> 
                                     This is the description
                                 </p>
                             </div>
                             </div>
                         </div>
                     </div>";

         }
     } else {
         echo "0 results";
     }
?>
                         </div>


<!-- Single products -->                         
                         <div id="product">
<?php
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM `products`";
     $result = $conn->query($sql);

     if ($result->num_rows > 0){
         // Output data of each rowt
          while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
             //echo "Brand : " . $row["brand"] . " - Product : " . $row["name"] . " - " . $row["description"] . " - Price : " . $row["price"] . "<br>";
             echo    "<div class='col-lg-2.4 col-md-3.4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 products " . $row['brandName'] . " all " . $row['product_range'] . "' id='products'>
                         <div class='hovereffect'>
                             <img class='img-responsive productimg' src='" . $row['img'] . "' alt=''>
                             <div class='overlay1'>
                                 <h2> " . $row['name'] . "</h2>
                                 <p> 
                                     " . $row['title'] . "
                                 <br>
                                 <br>
                                     " . $row['price'] . "
                                 <br>
                                 <a href='#'>
                                     Add To Cart 
                                 </a> 
                                 </p>
                             </div>
                             <div class='overlay2'>
                             <div class='overlay3'>
                                 <p> 
                                     " . $row['description'] . "
                                 </p>
                             </div>
                             </div>
                         </div>
                     </div>";

         }
     } else {
         echo "0 results";
     }
 ?>
                         </div>
```

this is the jquery i have at the moment, but it only displays the products, not yet filter them.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
         $("#labelSelect").click(function(){
             $("#product_range").hide();
             $("#product_group").show();
             $("#product").show();

             $("." + $("input[type='radio'][name='selector']:checked")).show();
             $("products:not(." + $("input[type='radio'][name='selector']:checked") + ")").hide();
         });
     });
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It does not look like you have made any attempt at this yourself. Therefore this looks more like a specification than a question about coding **SO does not provide free coding services**

Comment: You have not said WHAT is wrong. You asked for help but your question is very broad and when running your code you have not displayed any error messages that might have appeared. I second RiggsFolly in closing for the resons he mentioned as well as mine

Comment: @RiggsFolly I am not after a free coding service, just a point in the right direction, I have tried other ways to make this work but every time come up with nothing. With a point in the right direction I believe I will be able to solve this myself.

Comment: if there are any errors in the query/PHP, then check for errors. If there are errors in the JS, then look at your console. Also use `var_dump()` and look at your HTML source; it's also a "tool".

Comment: thanks @Fred-ii- it isn't showing any errors though.

Comment: @Fred-ii- It is not showing any errors because he has not actually coded any of this stuff he is talking about. **Specification** He is showing code that curently works that he would like someone to add to to make it do all these extra things